# mySQL UNION fault

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Im having trouble with a sql join involving a union. I'm trying to pull a COUNT and a field from 2 tables but getting an error.

The query:

```
$sql_result7 = mysql_query("(SELECT COUNT (*) as alertcount, date as alertdate FROM alerts WHERE to_id='$id' AND date > '$lastcheck') UNION (SELECT COUNT (*) as mailcount, date maildate FROM mobmail WHERE to_id='$id' AND to_del=0 AND seen = '0')", $db); 

$rs7 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result7);
$alerts = $rs7[alertcount]; 
$mails = $rs7[mailcount]; 
$last_alert = $rs7[alertdate]; 
$last_mail = $rs7[maildate];
```

Is it something to do with the `date as alertdate` part?

The error im getting is:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

Comment: What kind of error did you got?

Comment: Also, my mySQL is rusty, but you have "date maildate" not "date as maildate" (not sure if that would change anything). Also, isn't "date" a reserved word?

Comment: There is no `JOIN` in your code. Is that the whole query?

Comment: That's a PHP error. Please post the PHP code.

Comment: Why don't you print the actual MySQL error message... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the space between `COUNT` and `(*)`, there is another issue. You can't use `$rs7[mailcount]` nor `$rs7[maildate]` in your PHP code because your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(*) as alertcount
    , date as alertdate 
FROM alerts 
WHERE to_id = '$id' 
  AND date > '$lastcheck' 
UNION 
SELECT 
      COUNT(*)                      --- No "as mailcount" here
    , date                          --- No "as maildate" either 
FROM mobmail 
WHERE to_id = '$id' 
  AND to_del = 0 
  AND seen = '0'
```

and will return two rows and only 2 columns:

```
alertcount | alertdate
-----------|------------
 24        | 2012-01-04
 73        | 2011-11-11
```

---

Two ways to solve this problem:

Either keep the query (changing the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` to ensure that you always get 2 rows) and chnage the PHP to use the 2 rows.

Or change the query to:

```
SELECT alertcount, alertdate, mailcount, maildate 
FROM
      ( SELECT 
              COUNT(*) AS alertcount
            , date     AS alertdate 
        FROM alerts 
        WHERE to_id = '$id' 
          AND date > '$lastcheck' 
      ) AS a 
  CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT 
              COUNT(*) AS mailcount
            , date     AS maildate 
        FROM mobmail 
        WHERE to_id = '$id' 
          AND to_del = 0 
          AND seen = '0'
      ) AS b
```

Comment: ahh was wondering why it wasnt working. How could I fix this? Do i need to use UNION ALL or something to return both query results?

Comment: You can use the results from the 2nd row in PHP, can't you?

Comment: Well before this inner join query I had 2 seperate queries instead and it worked, but with this new query it's not doing what it should do. Its not returning the correct `mailcount`

Comment: There is another potential issue. What do you intend the `date` columns to show? You are actually grouping all the rows and counting them. There are probably many different dates there. Which one should be shown?

Comment: It means all combinations of rows of table1 and table2. Since both subqueries return 1 row exactly, there is one combination.